# Beaglebone Black ubuntu compiling Driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, driver, beagleboneblack

I'm pretty new to this environment, but usually I can muddle things out, so please bear with me.

In short, what I'm trying to do is compile a custom driver. What I've gone through and relevant information is listed below.

BBB running Ubuntu 14.04
kernel version: 4.1.1-ti-r2

As a jumping off point, I'm trying to follow the link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module).

As an interesting side note, when I use the command `apt-get install linux-kernel-headers`, it used kernel version 3.13.0-61.100. Does this mean I can use the repositories for kernel 3.13.0?

Just as an experiment, I tried this command: `apt-get source linux-source-3.13.0` to see what would happen. This resulted in the error: `"E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"`.

Perhaps I'm following the wrong example. If somebody knows of a tutorial somewhere that I could follow that would allow me to compile a Ubuntu driver on the BBB, that would also be hugely appreciated. I wasn't able to find anything in my various google searches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably fix your current hang up by following instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to progress slightly, by getting the 3.13 kernel headers installed using `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` or `sudo apt-get install linux-headers.3.13.0-61-generic` (not sure which one).

By hard coding in the kernel include location into the makefile, I was able compile a basic hello world driver. I've run into a separate issue now where the kernel doesn't accept the module. The most likely culprit at this point is due to the fact that the kernel I'm running is 4.1.1 and it was compiled for 3.13.0.

I'll be asking for more help in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps slightly counterintuitively, you'll want to `apt-get install linux-source`. *linux-source* does not have a source package, it is a package consisting only of sources.

Alternatively, you might want to `apt-get source linux-image`.

Either way, [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) contains some instructions for rebuilding a packaged Ubuntu kernel.